# Cpu utilisation of azure SQL database is showing zero

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, cpu-usage

I have moved a azure SQL database from one subscription to another.
After moving the database the cpu utilisation is showing zero .
Cpu may have been dead.
Please help me to fix the issue.
[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlXDb.png)

Comment: What Tier are you one? Maybe you are using serverless

Comment: Hyperscale:Gen4,1 vCore

Comment: Add a screenshot to the post, please

Comment: Please contact customer support to get them to investigate the issue.

Comment: Hi @vidya, what's the database status now?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani added screenshot

Comment: @leonyue the status is same cpu utilization is still zero

Comment: @vidya does the database active or inactive? I check my SQL database and it also zero. I still can connect and query the database. My database is not very large and price tier is General Purpose: Gen5, 2 vCores.

Comment: @vidya can you check how many storage used in the database?

Comment: @Leon yue the database is active, even I can connect and query the database -Hyperscale:Gen4,1 vCore

Comment: @vidya please change the database to DTU model and waiting for some hours to check the monitor data changes.

Comment: Hi @vidya, hope you are doing well! do you get any progresses?

Comment: I guess @franscesco is right. To be sure I have raised a request with Microsoft support team . waiting to hear from them ,will update .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below DMV ( in SSMS /Query Editor)  :

```
SELECT    
    AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU Utilization In Percent',   
    MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU Utilization In Percent',   
    AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average Data IO In Percent',   
    MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum Data IO In Percent',   
    AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average Log Write I/O Throughput Utilization In Percent',   
    MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum Log Write I/O Throughput Utilization In Percent',   
    AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average Memory Usage In Percent',   
    MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum Memory Usage In Percent'   
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;
```

I was able to see 76 percent cpu utilization using this query, still it's not showing on portal and Microsoft internal team is looking into it but at least I was able to see that cpu is not dead and it is responding.

[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rSZn.png)

Answer (score -1):

How to debug this:

1. Fire up SSMS and run a few queries. Some `SELECT` will be alright.

If you can retrieve data is all good. You probably moved to a higher tier with better performances.